# Sum of Infinite Series not converging. — why?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does the term in this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZKQ6.jpg) equal to infinity. 
I thought when a term goes to zero the sum of all the terms added over a series goes to a specific value.

What do I miss?

Comment: Google Harmonic series, or search Harmonic series on this site

Comment: For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2093530/269624

Comment: "What do I miss?" you miss the definition of convergence for the infinite series. It only converges if the sequence of **partial sums** converges, not the terms

Answer (score 0):

This is not in general true. For example the harmonic series diverges, even though the terms get smaller and smaller.

In fact we can use the harmonic series to see the above sum diverges. Using the limit comparison test we see that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x+1}}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$, so by the limit comparison test this diverges.